# How can I make FDT always build and run my main file?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder, fdt

When I push `F11` in Flash Builder, it does a full build and runs in the context of my main ActionScript file. When I do the same in FDT, it builds the last selected file in the Flash Explorer pane and runs in the context of that. While I can see how it could be useful, I'd much rather always run in the context of my entire application. How can I make FDT always build and run my main file?

Possibly relevant: I imported the project from Flash Builder into FDT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Window-Preferences, type "launch" in the quick search bar, click Run/Debug-Launching and check on the bottom Launch Operation "Always launch the previously lanched Application".

Comment: Yes. And that makes actually make more sense since there's actually no such thing as "main file" at all.

Comment: While this accomplishes what I need, why does my Flash Builder behave differently (its setting was identical to what FDT used to be)?

Comment: @Olson.dev - this is simply how FB and FDT evolved differently.  Design decisions made earlier in both products life cycles lead to this divergence.