# How can I make Eclipse/FDT build Main.as instead of the currently selected file?

Tags: eclipse, actionscript-3, fdt

I'm using FDT, and I want Eclipse to build my Main.as file instead of the currently selected file when I click debug/run. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your settings and the order you've done things...

If you right click on a file and choose 'Run As' or 'Debug As', FDT (Eclipse) will use that file to build your application around.

If you have 'Always launch the previously launched application' enabled (it should be enabled by default) then FDT will always use the last used launch configuration whenever the Run / Debug button is clicked. If none exists then it will run using the currently active file. To enable this setting, go to *Preferences > Run/Debug > Launching* and look at the bottom where *Launch Operations* is.

If you have a launch configuration already created, and it sounds like you do, you'll need to adjust the 'Main' file within that launch configuration. Do this by choosing 'Run Configurations...' via the Run button drop down.

I've written a tutorial about this. It should help you get through it.

http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/Launch_Configuration_Tutorial

Comment: Thanks. You mention that "Developers can set ANY class to act the Main or Document class of a project" but I'm not seeing the instructions on how to do this in your tutorial.

Comment: In the launch configuration window. See this updated screenshot. http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/File:07_012_updated.png

Comment: If I close the project and reopen it, it pops up the Run Configurations dialog. If I select 'Main' under 'FDT SWF Application' and then hit run, it builds fine until I close the project and open it again...

I want it to *always* build Main.as, period.

Comment: You need to make sure you have 'Always launch the previously launched application'. I talk about how to do it above.

Comment: Yes, I have that option set in Eclipse... I'm still experiencing the issue I described in my previous comment unfortunately.

Comment: Without more info, you can't be helped any more. There must be some other issue, setting or workflow step that is preventing this from happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at this thread?     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300717/how-can-i-make-fdt-always-build-and-run-my-main-file

Comment: Unfortunately that's not helping either. As I said this issue only seems to happen when I've closed the project and reopened it, and attempt to build it the first time... very annoying.